# Python-OpenCv error-261

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to Python-OvenCV programming. I'm using python idle to load and display image from folder. its showing the following error:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Python27\a.py", line 4, in <module>


cv2.imshow("abc",img)    
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215)   size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow**
```

my code is:

```
import cv2    
import numpy as np    
img = cv2.imread("C:\Users\Mayur\Desktop\ab.bmp",0)    
cv2.imshow("abc",img)     
cv2.waitKey()
```

I have searched for solutions but they are all for matlab and I'm using python IDLE.

Comment: are you sure about the path?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about the path. I have also tried many other ways but it gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found the solution already, but ill give an answer anyways.

This is a common mistake when trying to read files in python. in my experience python does not like the "\" when you are naming the file location. instead you should use a "/". Here is what is should look like:

```
img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Mayur/Desktop/ab.bmp",0)
```